# Redirect > from subfolder to its main folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect 403 page (sub-folder/) (Options -Indexes) to its main/up folder.

example original url >

`example.com/photos/artist/name/events.html`  ("name" folder contains many "events" html files)

but visitors somehow lands in >

`example.com/photos/artist/name/events/`  < which shows 403 error because "Options -Indexes" in .htaccess and no index page in that location.

I can add below line in .htaccess ..

```
Redirect /photos/artist/name/events/ http://example.com/photos/artist/name/events.html
```

but the problem is there is many event html files in /name/* and its not only for this directory, also to other /artist/name1 , /artist/name2 etc etc

```
/artist
   /name1
      /events1, 2, 3,.. .html
   /name2
      /events1, 2, 3,.. .html
```

I want like.. when visitors landing in

`example.com/photos/artist/name/events/`  > this need to redirect to

`example.com/photos/artist/name/` < this location has index.html so visitors can check the events.

is this possible ?

I tried below line and 403 ends up in internal error..

`Redirect /photos/artist/*/*/ /photos/artist/*/`   < i know this is stupid of me :/

I am not expert in this field so hope my question is understandable..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a regex for this. Assuming you still want to use mod_alias, instead of mod_rewrite for example, you need to use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`. For an url like `example.com/photos/artist/phil-collins/events/` you would need the following directive:

```
RedirectMatch temp /photos/artist/([^/]+)/events/ http://example.com/photos/artist/$1/
```

Comment: Mate, it worked!!

I added like this in .htaccess >

`RedirectMatch temp /photos/artist/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ http://example.com/photos/artist/$1/`

([^/]+)/([^/]+) < because artist "name" and "events" wont be same on other "name" and "events" folders.

Thank you very much!!!! :hugs: LOL

Comment: Don't know what you meant by mod_alias though.. I am newbie in this :/

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch <-- mod_alias is the name of the module you are using functions of.

Comment: seems like its not working if url ends without "/"

`http://example.com/photos/artist/name/event/` > works

`http://example.com/photos/artist/name/event` > 404 error

can fix this?

Comment: Use `/?` instead of `/` at the end of the url.